# Is the Java Heap Memory contiguous?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

I've seen people comment about Java Heap memory being contiguous and people say the contrary. Well, can someone give me a final answer and explain this question? Also, is there some kind of data structure in Java Heap as there is in Java Stack?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting from the [JVM spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#15730): *The memory for the heap does not need to be contiguous.* So your code shouldn't make assumptions about the continuity of the heap.

Comment: The memory for the heap does not need to be contiguous?

What does that mean ? It means that to fulfill the spec, you do not have to have a contiguous heap. It does not say that the heap SHOULD NOT be contiguous. HotSpot heap (Sun/Oracle JVM) is contiguous, I have performed tests that confirmed it. BTW, this sentence is there for other vendors, such as IBM, who have split up the heap into parts, most are non-contiguous, some are.

Comment: If your intent is to write Java code that will run on any JVM, not just the Sun/Oracle JVM, then you shouldn't make assumptions about the continuity of the heap. Further, your tests only demonstrate that the Sun/Oracle JVM *currently* has a contiguous heap. Future versions could adopt the IBM approach and break any code that assumes a contiguous heap.

Comment: Indeed, as soon as I switch to the G1 gc, it no longer is contiguous. I am just saying, by default it uses a contiguous heap, most likely for backward compatibility.

See http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/the-three-jvms.aspx
and
http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2013/01/difference-between-sun-oracle-jvm-ibm.html

Answer (score 6):

The real answer is, you don't know and should not care. There are different JVMs, and no one makes promise on anything but specification.

Comment: It is important to know; however, you should assume that it is not contiguous and plan accordingly.  This means less small objects and more large compact objects/classes to reduce cache misses and extended memory lookups.  Small objects are the bane of memory performance and cache misses.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the JVM but is definitely not guaranteed to be contiguous.  HotSpot uses a generational heap whereas IBM JDK and JRockit do not.  I believe both the IBM and JRockit garbage collection processes uses a sweep/compress algorithm which in practice should result in a contiguous heap.

Comment: > I believe both the IBM and JRockit garbage collection processes uses a sweep/compress algorithm which in practice should result in a contiguous heap.

It is slightly more complex than that. 
See
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/realtime/v2r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rt.doc.20%2Frealtime%2Fdiagnose_oom_understanding.html
There is a doc on Oracle about JRockit and non-continuous heap, I cannot find right now, don;t have time.